# domain name doesn't work with www ahead

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, domain-name

On my machine I'm using WAMP with virtual hosts. All I did was to add 127.0.0.1 my-project.loc line into system32\drivers\etc\host file and the following code into httpd-vhost.conf from the Apache2.2.11\conf\extra folder.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/my-project.loc"
    ServerName my-project.loc
    ErrorLog "logs/my-project.loc-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/my-project.loc.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

My question is how can i make the www.my-project.loc to work too. Can you give me the smart solution, because i assume that writing the same code but this time with ServerName www.my-project.loc isn't a good idea.

TY

Comment: DerfK is right about the hosts file, but don't bother with the rewrite, add the line that the unnamed user listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following line under the ServerName directive:
ServerAlias www.my-project.loc

Comment: Formatting is everything: `ServerAlias www.my-project.loc` This, along with DerfK's answer for the hosts file is the two things you need to do for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a second `<VirtualHost>` block  with `ServerName www.my-project.loc` and the same DocumentRoot

Ideally, the second block would use `mod_rewrite` to redirect (301) all requests to one "canonical" hostname rather than having two identical copies of your website. Example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*) http://my-project.loc/$1
```

Comment: Also, your hosts file will need to read `127.0.0.1 localhost my-project.loc www.my-project.loc`  Otherwise you won't be able to find www.my-project.loc

Comment: The second `VirtualHost` block is unnecessary (see the `ServerAlias` directive above) but adding that line to the hosts file is a great point.

Answer (score 0):

Add another line to your hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 www.my-project.loc
```

And then add this line after ServerName directive in your virtual host config:

```
ServerAlias www.my-project.loc
```